# I would like to minimize the size of my photo

Tags: java, user-interface

**I would like to minimize my photo size so that it will look exactly smaller (full image) **

```
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(""));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageIcon icon2=new ImageIcon(img);
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel();
    label5.setIcon(icon2);
    label5.setBounds(20,180,500,130);
    frame.add(label5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setBounds(). It is the job of the layout manager to set the size and location of Swing components.

You can use the `Image.getScaledInstance(...)` method to resize the image before you add the image to the ImageIcon.